# Cuda Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, cuda

I'd love to know if anybody got success to use CUDA on Saucy.

I installed it using apt-get, but cannot really understand how to make it work.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-dev
```

Nvidia is giving [doc](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) but for previous versions of Ubuntu,

Things are kind of different for saucy.

Any helps is warmly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good solution to this question at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380609/anyone-has-successfully-installed-cuda-5-5-on-ubuntu-13-10-64-bit). Be careful when installing CUDA under an Optimus system (as in notebooks with double GPU) because you have to pass the option `--optimus` when executing the CUDA toolkit installer.