# dpkg installation problem

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, cuda

When I am trying to install a package it is giving me this error.

```
deb @nvidia:/home/nvidia# sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1304-6-0-ea_6.0-13_armhfd
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cuda-repo-ubuntu1204' missing; assud
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cuda-license-6-0' missing; assumingd
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cuda-misc-6-0' missing; assuming pad
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cuda-command-line-tools-6-0' missind
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cuda-extra-libs-6-0' missing; assumd
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cuda-core-6-0' missing; assuming pad
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cuda-core-libs-6-0' missing; assumid
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cuda-samples-6-0' missing; assumingd
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cuda-headers-6-0' missing; assumingd
(Reading database ... 40716 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace cuda-repo-ubuntu1304-6-0-ea 6.0-1 (using cuda-repo-ubuntu1.
Unpacking replacement cuda-repo-ubuntu1304-6-0-ea ...
Setting up cuda-repo-ubuntu1304-6-0-ea (6.0-1) ...
OK
```

Ideas to resolve it are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

First fix the broken installation:

> sudo dpkg -r cuda-repo-ubuntu1304-6-0-ea

Follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380609/anyone-has-successfully-installed-cuda-5-5-on-ubuntu-13-10-64-bit#answer-387335) to install cuda toolkit.